# Apply constructor arguments from respective index in a list

Tags: scala

Say we have a class:

```
case class Header(a:String, b:String, c:String, d:String) //in reality its 16 arguments

val a = ("1","2","3","4") //or list. I think tuple is more useful as we can keep track of arity
```

What I wish is to apply all values of tuple `a` as constructor arguments to `Header`. Something like:

```
Header(a._0,a._1,a._2,a._3) //or
Header.curried(a._0)(a._1)(a._2)(a._3)
```

Above of-course has too much boiler plate as arguments had to be manually entered. Is there a way where I can simply apply tuple arguments in a loop or something to constructor based on its index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tupled` to convert the `apply` method of the case class companion to a function1 that simply takes a single tuple with all args required:

```
case class Header(a:String, b:String, c:String, d:String)
val a = ("1","2","3","4")

Header.tupled(a) // -> Header(1,2,3,4)
// The above is short for the line below, the result is the same
(Header.apply _).tupled(a) // -> Header(1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: Aha. I forgot about tupled!